# How can I reduce the amount of noise transferred through my exterior walls?

Tags: sound-proofing, noise-reduction

My apartment building is near a mosque and as you may already know when the Moslems pray they like to use loudspeakers. And I mean LOUD. As I live in an apartment I am not allowed to make any changes to the outside facade. Our corner unit has windows in the bedrooms and it could get really noisy. We are expecting a baby soon and are trying to find a way to cancel this noise to ensure good sleep for the baby. What kind of solution can you suggest? Preferably one that wont involve a lot of construction and wont break the wallet. I attach a pic of one of the bedrooms with the blinds drawn. [image]

Comment: First off, you're going to have trouble soundproofing glass. Secondly, babies can sleep through a surprising amount of noise if they're used to it.  If you tiptoe around when baby sleeps, they'll eventually wake to a pin drop. If, however, you make lots of noise, they'll learn to sleep through it (according to old wives).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Understood and agreed about the baby. Still though the loud noise Is annoying. Any solution or products you would recommend? Do those white noise products work well? Thanks

Comment: White noise machine effectiveness varies based on the individual. My 2 year old son sleeps like the dead with a white noise machine running. You could drop a tray of dishes outside his door and he won't stir. However, beyond drowning out some background noise, it doesn't seem to help my 7 month old daughter. Loud laughter in the other room wakes her. It just needs to be slightly louder with the white noise maker running.

Comment: You could try a using a fan, with the added benefit of air circulation.

Comment: Coming back to this guys. What is the best solution to this? Should I install a second window layer? Or sound proofing curtains? Or something else?

Answer (score 3):

There are soundproofing curtains and soundproofing panels that can be found through an internet search for *[soundproofing curtains](https://www.google.com/search?q=soundproofing%20curtains&oq=soundproofing%20curtains)*.

They are not cheap, window curtains starting in the $300 range for an average size window (and yours are much larger). Panels start at about $200 for a 4x8 foot unit and they still need to be hung on some sort of frame. Preframed versions are a good bit more.

Many people swear by white noise machines, but not all people find them effective.

Comment: Thanks very much! Yikes thats expensive, and where i am will probably cost double. I will look into them. Thanks again

Comment: I can't imagine any white noise machine that could mask a muezzin's call to prayer! Though if there were other effective measures, it may help mask the remaining sound that does get through.